# GREP for pattern and remove all the junk characters before or after the pattern

Tags: awk, grep, variable, for

I have a set of files in a directory. And every file will have a line called `---PUBG-xxxxx--` or `---PUBG-xxxxx,  PUBG-yyyyy ----`. Below is the output of the grep command.

```
grep "^--" FILE*.sql | grep "PUBG"

FILE1.sql:---PUBG-10901--
FILE2.sql:---PUBG-11617--
FILE3.sql:---PUBG-11625--
FILE4.sql:--PUBG-11724--
FILE5.sql:---PUBG-11720, PUBG-11406---
FILE6.sql:---PUBG-11403---
FILE7.sql:---PUBG-12021--
FILE8.sql:---PUBG-12207--
FILE9.sql:---PUBG-12270--
FILE10.sql:---PUBG-12552--
FILE11.sql:--- PUBG-14284--
FILE12.sql:--- PUBG-10908--
FILE13.sql:--- PUBG-15136---
FILE14.sql:--- PUBG-15163---
FILE15.sql:--- PUBG-15166---
FILE16.sql:-- PUBG-15059 --
FILE17.sql:-- PUBG-15252 --
```

The PUBG and its numbers will be random. All I need is file name and its associated PUBG value without any `--` before or after PUBG and its value. There can also be multiple PUBGs as like in `FILE5.sql:---PUBG-11720, PUBG-11406---`. I have written the below set for loop.

```
for (i in `grep "^--" FILE*.sql | grep "PUBG"`)
do
    FILE_NAME=`echo ${i} |  awk -F ":" {'print $1'}`
    PUBG_NO=`echo ${i} | awk -F "PUBG-" {'print "PUBG-" $2'}`
    echo ${FILE_NAME}
    echo ${PUBG_NO}
done
```

But the sample output for `PUBG_NO` is `PUBG-15166---` for `FILE15.sql`
and is `PUBG-11720,` for `FILE5.sql`.

I need all the PUBG values in a file for particular FILE_NAME without any `--`. 
The PUBG value of FIlE5.sql can be `PUBG-11720, PUBG-11406` How can this loop be improved to fetch the exact results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't need to write a loop. You could just pipe your ouput to sed. My attempt is as follows:

```
grep "^--" FILE*.sql | grep "PUBG" | sed -E 's/--+\ ?//g'
```

Which would give

```
FILE1.sql:PUBG-10901
FILE2.sql:PUBG-11617
FILE3.sql:PUBG-11625
FILE4.sql:PUBG-11724
FILE5.sql:PUBG-11720, PUBG-11406
FILE6.sql:PUBG-11403
FILE7.sql:PUBG-12021
FILE8.sql:PUBG-12207
FILE9.sql:PUBG-12270
FILE10.sql:PUBG-12552
FILE11.sql:PUBG-14284
FILE12.sql:PUBG-10908
FILE13.sql:PUBG-15136
FILE14.sql:PUBG-15163
FILE15.sql:PUBG-15166
FILE16.sql:PUBG-15059 
FILE17.sql:PUBG-15252 
FILE14.sql:PUBG-15163
FILE15.sql:PUBG-15166
FILE16.sql:PUBG-15059 
FILE17.sql:PUBG-15252
```

Here, I am using a sed substitue command which takes the form of

```
's/regular expression/substition/flag'
```

To further break down the command:

- The regular expression "--+\ ?" is the pattern you want to find and select. This can be read as "Find a pattern that has "-" followed by one or more consecutive "-" that is followed by zero or one " ". This will match "--", "---", and "--- " in your output. Note that you will need the -E flag for sed in order to recongize these quantifiers. [Here's a quick reference to brush up on the regex quantifiers like ? and +](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#iteration)
- Here, the substituion space is left empty. This will replace the found patterns with nothing and is an effective method to strip your output.
- The flag "g" indicates that the search will be global. Without this, the substitution will only happen for the first match on each line. Adding the g will make sure that every instance of that pattern on each line is replaced with nothing.

You could also apply those concepts to your initial grep command to perform only one search.

```
grep -E "^--+\ ?PUBG" FILE*.sql | sed -E 's/--+\ ?//g'
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for that.
But "sed" part is failing.
Gives me the following error.
`sed: invalid option -- E`

Comment: If the '-E' flag is failing, you might not have the extended regular expressions on your system. As a workaround, you can just use the "*" quantifier, which should work on just sed without the -E:  `sed 's/---*\ *//g'`

Comment: If the -E flag fails for the grep command as well, I'd try : `grep "^---*\ *PUBG" FILE*.sql | sed 's/---*\ *//g'`

Comment: Hi,
Thanks much, That works.
But It is not printing hypen between PUBG and Numbers like `PUBG-15236`, instead it prints `PUBG15236`, Anything can be added?

Comment: That's strange; since I'm searching for at least two consecutive "--"' it shouldn't remove those single dashes between the values... but as a quick fix, I'd pipe it all into sed to replace all "G" with "G-": `grep "^---*\ *PUBG" FILE*.sql | sed 's/---*\ *//g' | sed 's/G/G-/g'`

Answer (score 0):

Following AWK:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS="[,\n]"; }
/PUBG-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ { match($0,/PUBG-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/); print(FILENAME ":" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)); }
' FILE*.sql
```

Will give this output:

```
FILE11.sql:PUBG-14284
FILE1.sql:PUBG-10901
FILE3.sql:PUBG-11625
FILE5.sql:PUBG-11720
FILE5.sql:PUBG-11406
```

There are taken only 5 file into consideration:

```
$ ls FILE*.sql
FILE11.sql  FILE1.sql  FILE3.sql  FILE5.sql
```

Comment: HI, Thanks
The above AWK checks for wherever it finds PUBG-***** in a file.
It should check only for the line that starts with "--" or there may be 'n' number of hypens at the beginning of the line in any of the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '/^--/ && /PUBG/ {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        sub("^[- ]*", "", $i)
        sub("[- ]*$", "", $i)
        print FILENAME, $i
    } }' FILE*.sql
```

This would go through the original SQL files and would replace your pipeline.

The `awk` code extracts all lines that starts with `--` and that contains the string `PUBG`.  For each such line, it goes through the comma-delimited entries and strips any dash and space character from the start and end of each.  After trimming, it prints the resulting `PUBG-NNNN` string prepended by the filename that it was found in.